# Use SSH on Port 1337 or alternate port

Tags: ssh

what is the command to run ssh on port 1337 or alternate port?

Answer (score 5):

sshd with -p PORT:

> -p port
>   Specifies the port on which the server listens for connections (default 22). Multiple port options are permitted.  Ports specified in the configuration file with the Port option are ignored when a command-line port is specified.  Ports specified using the ListenAddress option override commandline ports.

You can edit sshd config(/etc/ssh/sshd_config):

```
Port 1337
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `Port` directive in the `sshd_config` file, or alternatively `sshd -p`.
See `man sshd` & `man sshd_config` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should read `man sshd` or `man sshd.conf` it is quite clear.

Comment: isn't there a command i can run per each instance of ssh?

Comment: No because you'd have to connect first then change port

Comment: ssh -p 2222 www.mywebsite.com

Answer (score 0):

Just change the (possibly commented, in which case you obviously need to uncomment it) "Port 22" line in your ssh server configuration file to "Port 1337".

Comment: i only have one client that uses port 1337, other use regular port so i would rather just use the command line to connect that port each time

Comment: ssh -p 2222 www.mywebsite.com

Comment: Do you want to connect to an ssh server running on port 1337, or do you want to run a server on that particular port? You comment seems to indicate the former while the original question seems to indicate the latter.